# Returning next highest value with binary search

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

In my binary search, I want to return the index of the next highest element if the target cannot be found.

E.g `[1,2,3,4,5,7]` if I were to search for `6` it should return the position of `7`.

I am testing with 
`aList = [2, 8, 17, 42, 79, 85]`

It works when I search for `3`, `18`, or `80`. However, it returns an index that is 1 lower than it should when I search for `9`, `43`, or `86`.

```
def recursiveBinarySearch(aList, first, last, target):

    if last - first + 1 <= 0:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = first + (last - first) // 2
        if aList[midpoint] == target:
            return midpoint
        elif last - first + 1 == 1:
            return midpoint 
        else:
            if target < aList[midpoint]:
                return recursiveBinarySearch(aList, first, midpoint-1, target)
            else:
                return recursiveBinarySearch(aList, midpoint+1, last, target)
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: when i search for  values 9 , 43 , 86 the index is -1 lower than it should be sorry about that

Comment: `bisect.bisect_left(aList, target)`. The source code is here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py

Answer (score 2):

```
aList = [1,3,5,6,8,9,10,12,34,56,78,456, 777]
def recursiveBinarySearch(aList, target, index):
    #aList = sorted(aList)
    print(aList, index)
    if len(aList) <= 1:
        if index==0 and aList[0]==target:
            return index
        else:   
            return index+1

    else:
        midpoint = len(aList) // 2
#        print(midpoint)
        if aList[midpoint] == target:
            return aList.index(target)+index
        else:
            if target < aList[midpoint]:
                return recursiveBinarySearch(aList[:midpoint],target, index)
            else:
                return recursiveBinarySearch(aList[midpoint:],target, index+len(aList[:midpoint]))

print(recursiveBinarySearch(aList,3,0))
```

This should work:)
Fixed a mistake for when you search for the first number.

Comment: thanks it works when i return last + 1 on my own code

Comment: The advantage of binary search is that it takes O(log n) time. Slicing takes O(n) time in standard Python implementation, so the advantage of binary search is defeated. Your solution should be efficient with Numpy arrays -- slicing them works in O(1). But with Python lists it is not good.